# Swift refactoring assistance

Tags: swift, refactoring

I have a meter laid out on a storyboard that is comprised of ten segments. There are an additional ten segments on top of the original segments that are colored to simulate a lighted segment  - these are outlets. (See image below.) Currently I am using a switch statement to hide and unhide each outlet/segment based on a constantly varying input level. But, as you can see in the code below, it's not pretty. I keep reading that polymorphism is often the way to improve a switch statement, but I can't see how that would help here.

```
switch input {
case 0...9:
  seg1.hidden = false
  seg2.hidden = true
  seg3.hidden = true
  seg4.hidden = true
  seg5.hidden = true
  seg6.hidden = true
  seg7.hidden = true
  seg8.hidden = true
  seg9.hidden = true
  seg10.hidden = true
case 10...19:
  seg1.hidden = false
  seg2.hidden = false
  seg3.hidden = true
  seg4.hidden = true
  seg5.hidden = true
  seg6.hidden = true
  seg7.hidden = true
  seg8.hidden = true
  seg9.hidden = true
  seg10.hidden = true
  ...
  and on and on for eight more levels.
```

[image]

Comment: Is it like if input value is less than 10 show only seg1, and if it is less than 20, show seg1 and seg2, and so on?

Comment: Exactly.  I expanded the code a bit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//You can have these segments in an array like this-

let segments = [seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4, seg5,seg6, seg7, seg8, seg9, seg10]

// Function that will setup the segments based on input

func setUpSegmentsForInputValue(segments:[UIView], value:Int) {
    for (index, segment) in segments.enumerate() {
        segment.hidden = (value/10)  != index
    }
}

// Call the function with whatever input values 
setUpSegmentsForInputValue(segments: segments, value: someValue)
```

Comment: Shripada and @riik - both answers look brilliant to me, thank you.  I accepted the answer that made the most sense to me, but I will definitely learn more about the "~=" operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all of your outlets to an array. Map the input to an "index range" and then decide in a for loop if outlet is in "index range". Then set hidden property accordingly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var seg1 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg2 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg3 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg4 = UIView()

...

let segs = [seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4]

let input = 19
let range = 0 ... input / 10

for (index, seg) in segs.enumerate() {
    if range ~= index {
        seg.hidden = false
    }else {
        seg.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Alternative (instead of the for loop):

```
@IBOutlet weak var seg1 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg2 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg3 = UIView()
@IBOutlet weak var seg4 = UIView()

...

let segs = [seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4]

let input = 19
let range = 0 ... input / 10

segs.enumerate().forEach { index, seg in
    seg.hidden = !(range ~= index)
}
```

Hope this helps.